# PermGen Error Tomcat8 / Spring Data /Hibernate on Deploy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, permgen

Working with a webapp using Tomcat8/Spring MVC/Spring Date/ Hibernate, every few deploys to the server or even saves in java development environment will cause the following error. Does anybody know how i can avoid or fix this? I have tried increasing the JVM to have more memory with no avail. Spring is setup using java config files and not the old web.xml method

```html
[ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2494)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:860)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
 at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$EntrySet.iterator(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:794)
 at java.util.AbstractMap$1$1.<init>(AbstractMap.java:322)
 at java.util.AbstractMap$1.iterator(AbstractMap.java:321)
 at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.clearClassLoader(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:164)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.resetCommonCaches(AbstractApplicationContext.java:881)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:563)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3831)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:292)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5616)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen other Tomcat PermGen issues, so I'd FIRST try using these args to see if it's sufficient before increasing your PermGen size.

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

If that doesn't work, check to make sure increase PermGen and not the heap size. You can set the PermGen size with the following JVM arg: `-XX:MaxPermSize=256M`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your application does not undeploy cleanly. You get the error on saves in your development environment, because this likely triggers a redeploy of your application.

this kind of error is really hard to debug, and if you find the cause you might not be able to resolve the issue on your own, because a library you use could be at fault. a good read on tracking down this kind of bugs can be found here: https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/hunting-down-memory-leaks-a-case-study.

i had the same issue years ago, and it turned out to be a problem in log4j. in the end we took the easy way out, and resolved to restarting the application server instead of redeploying the application.

in fact this is one of the reasons a lot of projects nowadays choose to deploy one app per appserver (or embedd the server) and just restart the whole thing on changes.

nonetheless, if you have the time, its worth tracking this down because it could well be a configuration error. and you learn a lot about your app and its runtime doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can resolve the issue by just adding my [ClassLoader Leak Prevention library](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention) to your application. At the time of this writing, that means this Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>se.jiderhamn</groupId>
  <artifactId>classloader-leak-prevention</artifactId>
  <version>1.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```

plus in your `web.xml` (won't be needed in version 2 soon to be released):

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.ClassLoaderLeakPreventor</listener-class>
</listener>
```

To learn more about third party libraries that may cause this problem and learn how you can debug this in both your own code and external libraries, see [this blog series of mine](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/).